# Choosing a JavaScript Asynch-Loader

Tags: learning, javascript, resources, async

I’ve been looking at various asynchronous resource-loaders and I’m not sure which one to use yet. Where I work we have disparate group-efforts whose class-modules may use different versions of jQuery (etc). As such, nested dependencies may differ, as well. I have no control over this, so this means I need to dynamically load resources which may use alternate versions of the same library.

**As such, here are my requirements:**

1. Load JavaScript and CSS resource
   files asynchronously.
2. Manage dependency-order and
   nested-dependencies across versions.
3. Detect if a resource is already
   loaded.
4. Must allow for cross-domain loading
   (CDN's)
5. (optional) Allow us to unload a
   resource.

**I’ve been looking at:**

- [Curl](https://github.com/unscriptable/curl)
- [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)
- [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/)
- [LABjs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff943568.aspx)

I might be able to fake these requirements myself by loading versions into properly-namespaced variables & using an array to track what is already loaded...but (hopefully) someone has already invented this.

**So my questions are:**

- Which ones do you use? And why?
- Are there others that my satisfy my
  requirements fully?
- Which do you find most eloquent and
  easiest to work with? And why?

**UPDATE:**
For those interested, I tried all the AMD libraries above (and more).  In the end, I went with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).  It's just cleaner and easier overall...and I'm glad to be using it.

Comment: For JavaScript, I don't think #5 is even possible. It might be theoretically possible for CSS, but I'm not sure if any browsers support that.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for commenting!  If the asynch-loader tracked & populated resources using object-variables...it's completely be possible.

Comment: Right, but the NEW constructor will duplicate the object, so if you create a new of something you called in, it'll still exist there. Why would you unload it anyway?

Comment: @user1525 Thanks for commenting! Unloading resources saves on memory.  I'll edit my question above with some thoughts on your comment (in a few minutes).  Thanks again!

Comment: jQuery already has a [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function for script injection.

Comment: when using jquery, i made a plugin called rloader http://code.google.com/p/rloader/

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this helps the asker? Does it meet all of the mandatory requirements? What advantages does it provide over the other options? Are there any downsides?

Comment: you might want to take a look at this too: http://onilabs.com/stratifiedjs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used RequireJS on serious projects, and I love it, but it's not really meant to be an asynchronous loader. It's really meant to be a module system. Asynchronous loading is provided in service to that goal. It can be pushed to fill any of your requirements, but its loading services are designed to load modules, not arbitrary files.

***Load JavaScript and CSS resource files asynchronously***: Requirejs loads any modules that you require using script tag injection, so asynchronously.

***Manage dependency-order and nested-dependencies across versions***: This is where RequireJS Shines. Modules may declare dependencies on other modules, and the load order will be extrapolated from that dependency declaration. There is also an order plugin, which can force order on dependencies.

***Detect if a resource is already loaded***: Requirejs will only load a module once.

***Must allow for cross-domain loading (CDN's)***: This is possible, but requires some configuration; You may set a specific URL for any module, and that will override the default location, so you can set it to a CDN.

RequireJS will serve best if you write modules using its format, and be least effective if you are using it to load raw javascript.

It also provides a build process that will merge your modules together into a single file for production.

Answer (score 3):

You could in theory just keep a list of scripts already loaded, and make a function that loads scripts that haven't yet been loaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/BDG/Dhdu7/2/

Comment: Or use Curl / RequireJS they have this and more features. And you don't have to maintain it yourself ;)

Comment: You forgot to mention clear structure and non-relative includes.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking at RequireJS and want to depend on CSS files, you can checkout the [CSSP RequireJS plugin](https://github.com/bbc-frameworks/CSSP) :

> CSS with Padding. This project implements a plugin for the [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)
>   project that allows modules to list CSS files as dependencies. This
>   allows RequireJS to wait until specific style rules are known to be in
>   effect before it releases the JavaScript module to be evaluated. This
>   would be useful if, for example, if your JavaScript module required
>   certain CSS rules, defined in a separate file, to be applied to the
>   DOM before it could be initialized.